# Rails inheritance for classes of same behaviour but different attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, associations, polymorphism, scalability

I have been researching on the best approach for my problem which I originally had implemented as a single table inheritance but am deeply concerned about the scalability, as potentially will have thousands of columns in the table.

So the problem is I would like to have products which the methods of each are exactly the same the only difference being the attributes each one contains. It seems that in this situation that mutli-class inheritance (not supported natively in rails?) would be the best approach or some sort of polymorphic associations.

I want to work towards the following

```
#product.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :title .....

 def to_s # some arbitrary method used by all extending classes
 ....
 end

end


#book.rb
class Book < Product
 attr_accessible :author...
end
```

So I want the book to inherit the methods from product and not for the product to know about the attributes required by each subclass. And if possible get all of the products through one query.

I need to know the best way of approaching this, and if I am doing it completely wrong, please note the code written above is just for example to simplify my problem.

Comment: Have you considered a document database such as Mongodb? You can just define attributes for each class and it would give you flexibility to use whatever attributes you want w/out needing to change the database table for all models.

Comment: Have not considered using Mongo, was planning to use postgres as database will have potentially millions of rows and decided that postgres would be the most reliable in those respects. Is it not feasible to implement this structure in postgres or mysql? I come from a stronger OO background and this is a very simple thing to do in other languages :P

Comment: I was assuming that each model would have different columns, which is why I suggested something that was schema-less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a module and include it in several different models.

First, create a file in your lib directory

i.e.) my_module.rb

```
module MyModule
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Then, make sure the module is loaded when your Rails App starts:

In config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Finally, include it in your models:

i.e.) app/models/thing.rb

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

  include AdditionMod
end
```

You can test it in the console:

```
@thing = Thing.create(first_name: "Awesome", last_name: "Module")
@thing.full_name
=> "Awesome Module"
```

Comment: Wow, feel like a little bit of an idiot now. Thanks for the nice elegant solution. Another silly question is there a way in which I can    "share" attributes across multiple tables using something similar to this (as opposed to writing a migration to do it)

Comment: Without going into a lot of detail, look into [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I can use H-store in conjunction with postgres that allows me to have a column that contains a schema less hash that can be used with the power of postgres (for an example take a look at http://hstoredemo.herokuapp.com/)